# Problems with javascript and h:commandLink

Tags: javascript, jsf

```
                <a href="#" onclick="return oamSubmitForm('display_form','display_form:link_prev');" id="display_form:link_prev"> &lt; Prev</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="return oamSubmitForm('display_form','display_form:link_next');" id="display_form:link_next"> Next &gt;</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="14" height="5" nowrap="nowrap" class="WhiteRow"></td>
    </tr>
    <input type="hidden" id="display_form:removeUserId" name="display_form:removeUserId" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="display_form:remove111" name="display_form:remove111" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="display_form:remove222" name="display_form:remove222" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="display_form:showPrev" name="display_form:showPrev" value="true" />
    <input type="hidden" id="display_form:showNext" name="display_form:showNext" value="true" /> 
    <tr>
        <td colspan="14" height="30" nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
            <input type="button" class="disabledfield" id="button_edit" value="Edit Details" onclick="populateEditRow();" />
            <input id="display_form:button_remove" name="display_form:button_remove" type="submit" value="Remove" onclick="populateRemoveRow();;" class="disabledfield" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="10"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The above HTML is what the JSF renders. When clicking on Prev / Next , I am getting javascript error as 'invalid Argument' , The JSF has created some functions like oamSubmitForm and several others.

What could be the problem? anything obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like that you're using [MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org). I don't recognize that function as from [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net). At least, this unhelpful JavaScript error is typical for the JS engine of the MSIE browser.

Have you tried a different (better) browser? For example [FireFox](http://getfirefox.com)? Does it work there or not? If not, did you try [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)'s JS debugger to determine the root cause of this JS error? If it's obviously caused by a bug in the JS function generated by MyFaces, then you need to try upgrade MyFaces to the latest version (or just replace by Mojarra). If upgrading MyFaces doesn't help, then report an issue at their issuetracker along with the smallest possible working snippet of the exact JSF code which reproduces this problem, along with detailed version information of the browser(s) used.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I will try to debug with Firebug.As far as my analysis, there is a function for clearing hidden inputs before submitting the form, wondering - what could be the issue?!

Comment: It is probably a MyFaces Bug and I dont see this bug when the page is rendered in Firefox. Accepting this as an answer.